# ServiceStack in ORMLite how do I make a simple reference to a parent table?

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I have 2 tables, the parent table holds definition fields for a history table. I am trying to reference the foreign key of the def table in the history table, but when I run this code, the referenced object is always null.

What did I do wrong?

```
[Alias("DOCMGR_PublishHistories")]
public class PublishHistory
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public int DocumentDefinitionId { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public DocumentDefinition DocumentDefinition { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset RequestedAt { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    [Required]
    public string RequestedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset EffectiveDate { get; set; }
}

[Alias("DOCMGR_DocumentDefinitions")]
public class DocumentDefinition
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLength(50)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
    public virtual string LegalDocType { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLength(50)]
    public virtual string LegalDocSubType { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLength(256)]
    public virtual string DisplayTitle{ get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLength(50)]
    public virtual string EntityName{ get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLength(256)]
    public virtual string EntityUrl{ get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added a [Live Example of this on Gistlyn](https://gistlyn.com/?gist=58b8111c74c300f66281b0dc0a5c90ee&collection=2cc6b5db6afd3ccb0d0149e55fdb3a6a) showing this working as expected:

You can save the `PublishHistory` table with its `DocumentDefinition` reference with:

```
db.CreateTable<DocumentDefinition>();
db.CreateTable<PublishHistory>();

db.Save(new PublishHistory {
    RequestedBy = "RequestedBy",
    RequestedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
    EffectiveDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
    DocumentDefinition = new DocumentDefinition {
        LegalDocType = "LegalDocType",
        LegalDocSubType = "LegalDocSubType",
        DisplayTitle = "DisplayTitle",
        EntityName = "EntityName",
        EntityUrl = "EntityUrl",
        IsActive = true,
    }
}, references: true);
```

Then use the [`Load*` APIs to load references](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#querying-pocos-with-references), e.g:

```
var row = db.LoadSingleById<PublishHistory>(1);
row.PrintDump();
```

Which outputs the `PublishHistory` table and its populated `DocumentDefinition` child reference:

```
{
    Id: 1,
    DocumentDefinitionId: 1,
    DocumentDefinition: 
    {
        Id: 1,
        LegalDocType: LegalDocType,
        LegalDocSubType: LegalDocSubType,
        DisplayTitle: DisplayTitle,
        EntityName: EntityName,
        EntityUrl: EntityUrl,
        IsActive: True
    },
    RequestedAt: 2019-05-07T20:08:29.1437953+00:00,
    RequestedBy: RequestedBy,
    EffectiveDate: 2019-05-07T20:08:29.1437953+00:00
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned in my case that I am returning a list of PublishHistory objects. Do I need to call load every time on them?

Comment: @PaulDuer the `Load*` APIs are what loads the referenced types, so you would use them when you want the `PublishHistory` Types and its `DocumentDefinition` reference, you can still use OrmLite's other APIs on `PublishHistory` but they wont load its references.